# Wrapping Thrust Device Vectors in a struct?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am implementing a math algorithm that requires keeping ~15 different vectors of floats around.  I'd like to wrap all of these device vectors into a struct

```
typedef struct {
  thrust::device_vector<float> ...
} data;
```

and pass this struct around to different functions.  Is it possible to have such a wrapping?  When I try to initialize one such struct

```
data* mydata = (data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

I receive this error

error: typedef "data" may not be used in an elaborated type specifier

Also, I'm suspicious about mallocing a block of memory of size *data* when none of its contents reside in host memory

Comment: You're getting that error because you are doing `sizeof(struct data)`  `data` is already typedef'ed.  You should just do `sizeof(data)` I'm not responding directly to the idea of the usability of this approach. You may want to create your device vectors external to the struct, and then have a struct of `thrust::device_ptr<float>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the typedef error.  When you say have a struct of thrust::device_ptr<float>, do you mean:

1) create foo = thrust::device_vector<float>, fill it with data
2) malloc struct data which is a struct of device_ptr, not device_vector
3) assign data->bar = foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the original error described in the title is not thrust related, but due to use of `struct data`, when `data` is already typedef'ed.

In response to the additional question posed in the comments, I merely was trying to state that I had not fully thought about the ramifications of using `thrust::device_vector<>` inside a struct.  When I said maybe consider using `thrust::device_ptr<>` instead, I had in mind something like this, which seems to work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#define N 10

typedef struct {
  thrust::device_ptr<float> dp1;
  thrust::device_ptr<float> dp2;
  int i;
} data;


int main(){

  thrust::negate<int> op;

  data *mydata = (data *)malloc(sizeof(data));
  thrust::host_vector<float> h1(N);
  thrust::sequence(h1.begin(), h1.end());
  thrust::device_vector<float> d1=h1;
  mydata->dp1=d1.data();
  mydata->dp1[0]=mydata->dp1[N-1];

  thrust::transform(mydata->dp1, mydata->dp1 + N, mydata->dp1, op); // in-place transformation

  thrust::copy(d1.begin(), d1.end(), h1.begin());
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("h1[%d] = %f\n", i, h1[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Having said that, the original method of using `device_vector` inside a struct may work, I just don't know and have not explored it.